# Performing a record retrieval via WSProxy in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs, java, wsproxy

In my data extension, I have two fields / columns:

- JobID
- DE_NAME

In this use case i want to receive the value for JobID and DE_NAME (1st row only)

```
var queryAllAccounts = true;    
    var cols = ["JobID","DE_Name"];
    

//define data extension from where record / value is needed
    var DE_ContentDetails_ExternalKey = "1111-1111-1111-1111";
    
var filter = {
    Property: "CustomerKey",
    SimpleOperator: "equals",
    Value: DE_ContentDetails_ExternalKey
};
    
    var tables = api.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + DE_ContentDetails_ExternalKey + "]", cols, filter, queryAllAccounts);
    

Write(tables.JobID);
Write("<br>");
Write(tables.DE_NAME);
```

**Issue:** I am getting blank output, why?

Comment: hi, probably the same root cause like to this one: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/379736/how-to-target-a-retrieved-data-extension-in-a-for-loop-while-using-wsproxy -> `tables.Results` is the array holding your results. see also: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/358385/retrieving-data-extension-data-from-a-wsproxy-retrieve for the general explanation, and here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347770/script-activity-in-marketing-cloud for it being applied to an actual example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tables.Results as mentioned by @Jonas Lamberty.
This is also mentioned in the doc: "*The response is an object with four properties from the APiObjects SOAP items*"
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_WSProxy_basic_retrieve.html

Other thing is related to filter. As you are using DataExtensionObject, this represents a row within a data extension so use a filter based on any column of your DE.

See below example for reference:

```
    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var queryAllAccounts = true;
    var cols = ["SubscriberKey","EmailAddress"];

    var DE_ContentDetails_ExternalKey = "111-111-111-1111";

    var filter = {
        Property: "SubscriberKey",
        SimpleOperator: "isNotNull",
        Value: ""
};

    var tables = api.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + DE_ContentDetails_ExternalKey + "]", cols, filter, queryAllAccounts);

    //Write(Stringify(tables.Results));

    for (var i = 0; i < tables.Results.length; i++) {
 
        var result_list = tables.Results[i].Properties;
        var obj = { };
        for (k in result_list) {
            var key = result_list[k].Name;
            var val = result_list[k].Value
            Write(key + "<BR>");
            Write(val + "<BR>");
            }
}
```

or if you want to keep it simple, you can use SSJS DataExtension.Init and Rows.Retrieve();
[Retrieving and Displaying the records from a data Extension using SSJS or WSProxy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301320/retrieving-and-displaying-the-records-from-a-data-extension-using-ssjs-or-wsprox)